# Wait vs No wait in Synchronized methods (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement, concurrency, wait

Hi I'm pretty new to Java and now I'm getting into java concurrency. And I have a little doubt about Synchronized methods: i have seen that I can get the same results using an If else inside a Synchronized method, checking every time If the condition to do an action is fullfilled, as using a wait / notify approach.

Since i get the same result I'm wondering If the If else approach has any advantages or disadvantages over t'he wait and notify approach? I supose that efficiency will be a disadvantage, since If is always checking the  condition, Who le wait Just stops and waits for notify. But are any other advantages or disadvantages?

Thx!

Comment: Can you show the code you're trying to compare?

Comment: These concepts are not contradicting. In fact, you should *always* check the condition first, before going to wait, as otherwise, you might wait forever, if the condition is already fulfilled. On the other hand, if the condition is not fulfilled, it should be impossible to poll successfully via a loop, as that would be an indicator that the other thread did not use `synchronized` properly when changing the condition. The key point is, that `wait` temporarily releases the monitor, allowing another thread to enter `synchronized` code changing the condition you’re waiting for.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two concepts. If-Else vs Wait-Notify are totally different. You want two threads to communicate with **each-other** that is where Wait-Notify would be used while if-else is general conditional statement.

You **cannot** have two threads communicate with each other simply using if-else condition. You can write your code that makes it look like it does however you are simply not allowing threads to interact with each other.

Moreover it can lead to undesirable consequences/computational states. Sooner or later you would have hotchpotch code.

Answer (score 1):

synchronized block makes the code thread safe. You would want to use `wait()` and `notify()` or `notifyAll()` if you want to be more efficient.

For example if your shared resource is a list, multiple threads share. If you put it in synchronized block of a monitor then threads will constantly jump in and run the code, during context switches. Even if the list is enpty!!

The `wait()` is hence used on the monitor (the object inside the `synchronized(..)`) as a mechanism to 'tell' all threads to chill out and stop using CPU cycles until further notice or `notifyAll()`.

```
synchronized(monitor) {

    while( list.isEmpty() ) 
       monitor.wait();
    doSomething(...)
}
```

In the above example, `doSomething()` will be executed **only** when the list is not empty, after another thread executed `notify()` or `notifyAll()` somewhere else in the code.

- [read more why use while surrounding wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())

**BUT** with the following code:

```
synchronized(monitor) {

    if(!list.isEmpty())
        doSomething(...)
}
```

When a thread comes in to the synchronized block, there are 3 possible scenarios:

1. The list is empty: `doSomething()` will not be executed.
2. The list is NOT empty: `doSomething()` may be executed properly, or...
3. If there was a context switch right after the `if` and before `doSomething`, and the other thread got all list's items out, after another context-switch out thread will execute `doSomethig()` on an empty list.

So, just to sum everything up, if you use wait/notify, you guarantee more efficient code! thread will not work when they don't need to.

Comment: If the other thread is using `synchronized` properly, scenario 3 can’t happen, as that’s the point of a `synchronized` block, guaranteeing that the other threads can’t interfere. On the other hand, if the other thread fails to use `synchronized` correctly, it will break the loop based code as well, as there is no fundamental difference between an `if` and a `while` in that regard. In both cases, `doSomething(…)` follows the `isEmpty()` check and relies on `synchronized` preventing in-between changes.

Comment: You're right, I just wanted to emphasize another possible idea. And the While is a according to the documentations in the given link.